# Does a lower, reactive Dodge Dice Pool replace the current Pool in W:tA 2nd edition?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

**Does a lower Dodge Dice Pool introduced via reactive Dodging replace (that is force a recalculation of) the current Pool in Werewolf: the Apocalypse, 2nd edition?**

P.226 of the core rulebook says the following:

> "Any time someone attacks a character, she has the option of dodging.
>   In fact, a player may announce at any time that her character is using
>   an action (or part of one, by dividing her Dice Pool) to dodge, simply
>   by declaring, 'Dodge!' before the opponent makes an attack roll. (...)
>   The required roll is Dexterity + Dodge."

Let's say I wish to both Claw and Use a Computer in my round (weird but whatever). My Claw pool is 6 dice, my Computer pool is 4 dice, therefore I take the lower of the two - Computer's 4 dice - and split that between Clawing to which I assign 3 dice and Computering which gets the remaining one.

My Dodge dice pool has 2 dice, and I *don't* declare my plan to use it in advance, during Stage 1 of Combat, but when an opponent is about to attack me in Stage 2, I decide to do it anyway as per the above quote.

Does my Dodge pool of 2 dice replace my 4 dice pool (that I got from Computer Use), letting me dodge with 1 or two dice and leaving 1 or zero dice for the two actions that I did announce during declaration?

Or do I take away up to two dice (my max Dodge pool) from the Computer-based pool of 4, leaving 2 dice for the other two actions? (But if it's the latter, why doesn't my Dodge pool replace the 4 dice, larger pool, when during declaration the 4 dice pool ousted the 6 dice Claw pool?)

Or am I misunderstanding this completely?

Please, clarify using this example, if possible. Thanks.

Note, please, that I know my question is a near duplicate of [How to divide the Dice Pool reactively](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44433/how-to-divide-the-dice-pool-reactively). However, I'm not clear about the exact Dice Pools even after reading about the answers there, unfortunately.

Also, I know that question titles aren't supposed to include specific game titles these days. However, since there's no specific W:tA 2nd edition tag, and it's that version of the game that I'm primarily interested in, answers referencing other editions or other oWoD games (such as Vampire v20, for example) are second best only - though way better than nothing, obviously.